# Structure of “need something back”

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, semantic-roles

What is the structure of the following sentence?

> I need my history book **back**.

What is the grammatical role of the word "back"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it **down**.

Hand it **over**.

Send it **out**.

I need it **back**.

These words indicate general direction, movement in space.  I need you to **return** it to me.  This history book must make a round-trip. I've handed it over to you and would like you to send it in the opposite direction.

> She flew from London to New York and then she flew back.

Are you able to understand their function in the sentence without affixing a label to them?